# Remove non-duplicate rows from Numbers

Tags: iwork-numbers

I have Numbers file in Mac OS with 3 columns

```
GEO_ID          GEO_ID2 FIPS
05000US01001    1001    12121
05000US01003    1003    28061
05000US01005    1005    21095
05000US01007    1007    28023
05000US01009    1009    28139
05000US01011    1011    28159
05000US01013    1013    51141
05000US01015    1015    51105
05000US01017    1017    28129
05000US01019    1019    28049
05000US01021    1021    37123
05000US01023    1023    21207
05000US01025    1025    21011
05000US01027    1027    21051
05000US01029    1029    5095
05000US01031    1031    28163
05000US01033    1033    28141
05000US01035    1035    28051
05000US01037    1037    47139
05000US01039    1039    28017
05000US01041    1041    5061
05000US01043    1043    40061
05000US01045    1045    28151
05000US01047    1047    22117
05000US01049    1049    47061
05000US01051    1051    28145
05000US01053    1053    40127
05000US01055    1055    28107
05000US01057    1057    54077
05000US01059    1059    5017
05000US01061    1061    37155
05000US01063    1063    28043
05000US01065    1065    28079
05000US01067    1067    29133
05000US01069    1069    47063
05000US01071    1071    28135
05000US01073    1073    13271
05000US01075    1075    12075
05000US01077    1077    12107
05000US01079    1079    28063
05000US01081    1081    5135
05000US01083    1083    37091
05000US01085    1085    45089
05000US01087    1087    22009
05000US01089    1089    47049
05000US01091    1091    28065
05000US01093    1093    13259
05000US01095    1095    21147
05000US01097    1097    13017
05000US01099    1099    21109
05000US01101    1101    21063
05000US01103    1103    28127
05000US01105    1105    12023
05000US01107    1107    48373
05000US01109    1109    28031
05000US01111    1111    13069
05000US01113    1113    21013
05000US01115    1115    13095
05000US01117    1117    22041
05000US01119    1119    28007
05000US01121    1121    5149
05000US01123    1123    37083
05000US01125    1125    1099
05000US01127    1127    22001
05000US01129    1129    28155
05000US01131    1131    21153
05000US01133    1133    28113
05000US02013    2013    47019
05000US02016    2016    28021
05000US02020    2020    54047
05000US02050    2050    12093
05000US02060    2060    13107
05000US02068    2068    22083
05000US02070    2070    48279
05000US02090    2090    
05000US02100    2100    
05000US02105    2105    
05000US02110    2110    
05000US02122    2122    
05000US02130    2130    
05000US02150    2150    
05000US02164    2164    
05000US02170    2170    
05000US02180    2180    
05000US02185    2185    
05000US02188    2188    
05000US02195    2195    
05000US02198    2198    
05000US02220    2220    
05000US02230    2230    
05000US02240    2240    
05000US02261    2261    
05000US02270    2270
```

I would like to compare FIPS with GEO_ID2. If any of GEO_ID2 is NOT present in FIPS column, then those rows should be deleted.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT :**
I'm sorry! I misread the whole Numbers thing. This may help you more with what you are trying to do: 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4266599?start=0&tstart=0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------You could create a simple java program with a map to do this, however I am not sure if that is too complex for what you are trying to accomplish.

If it is not to complex, you can do something like set a map for your GEO_ID (key), GEO_ID2 (value), and FIPS (value). Then create a list for your FIPS column. Using some logic to iterate through the map, compare each GEO_ID2 value with the entire FIPS list. If a GEO_ID2 is not found in the FIPS list, simply use a remove method to delete the row from the map.

Not sure if this helps or is too complicated, but I hope it does and is not!